# sorting multidimensional arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort an array, but by default I can only get it sorted by the record number.

i.e. the array looks like this for example

```
array(0=array('id','username'), 1=array('id','username'));
```

if I try to sort it, it sorts by the `0` and `1` values, I cannot get it to sort into the `id` & `username` array.

How can i sort the main array acording to the username in the child arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do,

Sorting using `ids`

```
$a = array(array('idC','usernameC'), array('idA','usernameA'), array('idB','usernameB'));
$id = array();
foreach ($a as $key => $row)
{
    $id[$key] = $row[0];
}
array_multisort($id, SORT_ASC, $a);

print_r($a);
```

will output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => idA
        [1] => usernameA
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => idB
        [1] => usernameB
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => idC
        [1] => usernameC
    )

)
```

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/Lc4xmu)**